# Can I set svelte style css attribute values using variables passed in to a component

Tags: syntax, svelte

I want to create a svelte component that receives the name and path of an image. I want to have the component set the image as the "background-image" using CSS.

I've tried the following which does not seem to work...

Component called in ***App.svelte***:

```
<Image image_url='./images/image1.jpg' />
```

***Image.Svelte***

```
<script>
export let image_url;
</script>

<style>
.image{
    position:relative;
    opacity: 0.70;
    background-position:bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url({image_url});
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="image">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

When I inspect the component the css for background_image is:

```
background-image: url({image_url});
```

Is it possible to have the variable converted in the CSS?

Comment: I guess the answers here are out of date. See https://svelte.dev/tutorial/style-directive .

Answer (score 74, accepted):

No. Component styles are shared between *all* instances of a component, either because they're statically extracted to a .css file, or because they're injected into a single `<style>` element that all components reference. If it were possible to put variables directly inside the component's `<style>`, it would mean that Svelte would need to create encapsulated styles *per-instance*, which would be detrimental to performance and would consume a lot more memory.

There are two ways to approach this. The first is to use inline styles for anything that can change per-instance:

```html
<script>
export let image_url;
</script>

<style>
.image{
    position:relative;
    opacity: 0.70;
    background-position:bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* background-image: url({image_url}); */
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>

<!-- <div class="image"> -->
<div class="image" style="background-image: url({image_url});">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

The second, particularly if you need to use values in multiple places, is to use CSS variables:

```html
<script>
export let image_url;
</script>

<style>
.image{
    position:relative;
    opacity: 0.70;
    background-position:bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* background-image: url({image_url}); */
    background-image: var(--image);
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>

<!-- <div class="image"> -->
<div class="image" style="--image: url({image_url});">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ...or 3. use "framework-agnostic css-in-js solution" as core team [suggests](https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-css-in-js). it's kind more flexible since inline styles does not handle media queries, pseudoclasses and pseudoelements.

Comment: btw I'm the creator of Svelte, I wrote that article ;) CSS-in-JS has its uses but I wouldn't generally recommend using it to solve this particular problem, it's probably overkill

Comment: @RichHarris, if this is *overkill*, then what is the alternative? I want to delegate these changes to the component where the parent can deliver a 'context' to customize in the child component's css styling, the alternatives break the clean separations

Answer (score 17):

You can now pass css variables directly as props: https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives---style-props

```html
<Image --background-image='url(./images/image1.jpg)' />
```

In `Image.svelte`

```css
background-image: var(--background-image, url(./images/default.jpg));
```

Comment: @coyotte508, is there a way in the *var* function that takes the prop name and the variable value to add a default? How can some logic be attached to it? Is it possible to make this prop inclusion optional for the parent component in adding it?

Comment: @Vass, no. You would need to set it as a variable, e.g. "backgroundImage" where you would have access to the string in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Think of Svelte  block as a CSS black box. You can't use javascript variables in the same way that you can't use them in a css file in the browser.

But...since it's a CSS box, you can always use scss and compile your  block using a svelte preprocessor like [this one](https://github.com/kaisermann/svelte-preprocess). Then you can just do

```html
<script>
export let image_url;
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "my/path/to/variables";

.image{
    position:relative;
    opacity: 0.70;
    background-position:bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(#{$image_url});
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="image">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what you are asking for in the following way:

```
<script>
  export let image_url;
</script>

<div class="image" style="--image_url: url({image_url})">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>

<style>
  .image{
    background-image: var(--image-url);
  }
</style>
```

The  in the html part of the component has access to the props, so can pass the prop to style as a CSS variable. The CSS variable can then be used in the background_image directly.