# Variables in <style> tag?

Tags: javascript, css, svelte, sveltekit

Is it possible to have variables in the  tag of a component with SvelteKit? For example I can get this to work:

```
<div class="mainContent" style="background-image: url('{backgroundImage}');">
```

But the following doesnt:

```
<style>
    main {
        background-image: url('{backgroundImage}');
        height: 85vh;
    }
</style>
```

Is it possible to get the latter to work? I ask because I want to be able to set a :before on that background image, which I don't velieve can be done inline.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set svelte style css attribute values using variables passed in to a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57174373/can-i-set-svelte-style-css-attribute-values-using-variables-passed-in-to-a-compo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my knowledge, I would use

```
let backgroundImage = '..../../'

<div class="mainContent" style="--bg-img: url({backgroundImage})">


<style>
    main {
        position: relative;
        background-image: var(--bg-img);
        ....
    }
    
    main::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute; 
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-image: var(--bg-img);
        ....
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you this works! Is there anyway to use the variable in main:before ?

Comment: Hi, @sylargaf. Yes, you can. I have edited the answer. Take a look.

Comment: You're the best, thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use css property(variable) as

```
<style>
    main {
        background-image: var(--backgroundImage);
        height: 85vh;
    }
</style>
```

then you can set value to this property dynamically using javascript as

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
          "--backgroundImage",
          "url(myimage.png)"
        );
```